# Prolog - syngeneic lists

Tags: prolog

Two lists are syngeneic if have the same length and all the elements are the same except first and last. I have managed to do the comparisons between the lengths but how  to see if the elements is the same except first and last of two lists.
Here is my code:

```
sug([H|T],[H1|T1]) :-
   length([H|T],N),
   length([H1|T1],M),
   N==M.
```

> e.x. of what is syngeneic list  -> sug([a,b,c,d],[d,b,c,a])

Comment: Do you need to check that the first and the last elements of the list are non-equal? For example, are identical lists considered syngeneic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumming there has to be at least two elements on the lists (so that they differ in each corresponding list), you can use `append/3` to match the intermediate list and check that the first and last differ:

```
sug([HL|LTail], [HR|RTail]):-
  HL \= HR,
  append(L, [LL], LTail),
  append(L, [LR], RTail),
  LL \= LR.
```

If first and last item does not need to be different (may or may not) then the procedure would just look:

```
sug([_|LTail], [_|RTail]):-
  append(L, [_], LTail),
  append(L, [_], RTail).
```

Comment: `sug([a],[b])` fails. Intended?

Comment: @false: intended, although right now I'm not sure what OP really wanted... My solution explicitly considers lists with at least two elements (a 'first', and a 'last') and the middle elements which have to unify between the two lists...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with several rules:

1. Empty lists are syngeneic
2. Lists are syngeneic when their tails are the same except for possibly the last element
3. Empty lists are the same
4. Lists with only one element are the same for the purposes of rule 2
5. Lists are the same for the purpose of rule 2 if their heads match and their tails are the same for the purpose of rule 2.

There is no need to check the length explicitly, because the rules above would never match two lists with different number of elements.

Here is how the above rules can be coded in Prolog - essentially, there is a line-for-line match:

```
sug([], []).
sug([_|T1], [_|T2]) :- sameExceptLast(T1, T2).
sameExceptLast([], []).
sameExceptLast([_], [_]).
sameExceptLast([X|T1], [X|T2]) :- sameExceptLast(T1, T2).
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/jMxL8D).

Comment: `sug([a,b,c],[a,b,c])` succeeds when it shouldn't (according to OPs rules, first and last element must differ)

Comment: `sug([a,b],[b,b]).` succeeds twice, otherwise nice. A tiny ambiguity is there in "all the elements are the same except first and last". Does this imply that the first elements *have* to be different or not?

Comment: @gusbro I am not 100% sure if "except first and last" means what it says, or "except *possibly* first and last". I added a comment to clarify.

Comment: @false I posted the same comment to the OP at the same time with you :) As far as `sug([a,b],[b,b])` goes, back in my Prolog days I would put a "cut" in the `sameExceptLast([_], [_])` rule, but I know it's no longer considered "kosher", and I am not 100% sure how to avoid it. Should I make the last rule `sameExceptLast([X|T1], [X|T2]) :- T1 \= [], sameExceptLast(T1, T2).`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: you might consider dif/2 to disambiguate.

Answer (score 0):

Why not, in SWI-Prolog :

```
sug(L1, L2) :-
    append([[_], Ls, [_]], L1),
    append([[_], Ls, [_]], L2).
```